# Apache Archiva /fileUploadService request body example

Tags: rest, archiva

I want to use Archiva like a stand-alone artifact repository for our bin-files. I need to have a possibility to upload files not via archiva's upload page. I started to look in the documentation and found rest api  /fileUploadService. 
There we have :

Mount Point: /archivaUiServices/fileUploadService

POST
Available Since: 1.4-M3

Request Body
element:    (custom)
media types:    multipart/form-data

I is it correct that i should put an html/json custom request body to upload a file?

I never worked with this issue before, so I went googling the question and didn't found anything that would help me.

So there for I have such questions:

How must the body look for uploading a file like .dll for example and the whole request?

I am using a add-on to chrome advanced rest client to execute the requests, maybe there is some client that can do this work with rest api bild-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, I didn't get any help so I investigated the question and found this kind of a solution to upload a file with out using a rest api in archiva and emulating the ui

I used cURL for executing a http put request with such parameters

curl -v -u admin:adminpas --upload-file "X:\x\x.exe" http://x.x.x.x:8080/repository/win/test/update/1.4/update.exe

It created folders in repo and puted the file into the repository

For some time it solves my problem